# How to print a HTML page by link in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link to HTML page, 
How I can print the page in JavaScript?
I try to do:

```
var printContent = url;
var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
var uniqueName = new Date();
var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
var printWindow = window.open("", "_blank");

printWindow.document.write( printContent );
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
printWindow.close();

window.open(location);
```

But it print the url and  not the page.
What can I do? Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need some time to page load and then call print. Justa  guess might try that out

Comment: Not a blank window the content is fed later ` printWindow.document.write( printContent );` @BhojendraNepal

Comment: you need to use XHR request to a link, wait for response and then just print it as HTML

Comment: Whatever is in the printContent will print. As there is url(link)in the printContent it will just print the value and not the page. You ll need to use XHR as suggested by MysterX.

Comment: You could create an iFrame and add the page to it, then print the iFrame contents.

Comment: Thanks! What is "XHR request" ?

Comment: @ Phiter Fernandes I didn't understand your idea, Can you show me example that explain it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Remove line that opening new window. I have commented in below code. You will need jquery for this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            $.get('http://example.com', function(data) {                 
                var printContent = data;
                var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
                    var uniqueName = new Date();
                    var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
                    var printWindow = window.open("", "_blank");

                    printWindow.document.write( printContent );
                    printWindow.focus();
                    printWindow.print();
                    printWindow.close();

                    //window.open(location);
                    return;

            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! but he give me empty page :( ,What I have to write instead of 'http://example.com' ? My url?

Comment: what content you url page has. Does this page has permission to read data ?

Comment: About your URL, if it is from same domain then it might work (not sure) but if it is from another domain then you will get error of Cross Domain Blocked. So be sure whatever URL you will use, it has data and that is accessible as well.

Comment: Thanks! I do not see why I can surf to this address with this path, but when he shows me the page for printing that does not work.